# can not send multiple select values to django view

Tags: python, html, django, django-views, django-templates

I have a select and has multiple values but in the backend

`knowledge_keywords` list is empty

```
knowledge_keywords = request.POST.getlist('knowledge_keywords')
```

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon">
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="key_words_check_box" value="1">
        </span>
        <select class="hidden" id="keywords" name="knowledge_keywords" multiple="multiple" data-role="tagsinput">
        </select>


    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 0):

## Views.py

```
keywords = request.POST.getlist('keywords')
```

## in template

```
<select name="keywords" multiple="true">
    <option value="1">Keyword 1</option>
    <option value="2">Keyword 2</option>
    <option value="3">Keyword 3</option>
    <option value="4">Keyword 4</option>
    <option value="5">Keyword 5</option>
</select>
```

- try this and print keywords variable if it still gives an error then comment again and state what error is given, i have tried this, it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Don't write form in html, reuse **Django** logic.

You can create a Form class:

***Forms.py***

```
from django import forms

class MyForm(forms.Form):
    CHOICES = (
        ("option1", "option1"),
        ("option2", "option2"),
    )

    knowledge_keywords = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, choices=CHOICES
    )
```

***template.html***

```
<form method='post'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type='submit' value='submit'>
</form>
```

use the FormView provided by Django that help you to manage form in the view, for example:

***Views.py***

```
from django.views.generic import FormView
from forms import MyForm

class MyView(FormView):
    form_class = MyForm
    template_name = 'template.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # can you access to cleaned value in the form inside
        # form.cleaned_data['knowledge_keywords']
        # and you can execute query or something else
        
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can instead take all the options by jquery and put them in an input which is hidden.Then send them to backend

```
var SelectOptions = ''
// event listener when user submits the button
$("#buttonsubmit").click(function(){
    $("#keywords option").each(function(){
        SelectOptions  = SelectOptions + $(this).val().trim() + ' '
    });

    // put the values in  SearchKeyword input
    $("#SearchKeyword").val(SelectOptions)

});
```